# 8-puzzle solver by DFS and BFS

Tags: python

```
import Queue
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
sys.setrecursionlimit(200000)

class State:
def __init__(self, board, space, prev):
    self.board = board
    self.space = space
    self.prev = prev

adjacent = (
(3, 1),       # 0
(4, 0, 2),    # 1
(5, 1),       # 2
(0, 6, 4),    # 3
(1, 7, 3, 5), # 4
(2, 8, 4),    # 5
(3, 7),       # 6
(4, 6, 8),    # 7
(5, 7)        # 8)

GOAL = [0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to solve 8-puzzle so that I made as the above and made BFS (Breadth First Search) as follows:

```
def bf_search(start):
    q = Queue.Queue()
    q.put(State(start, start.index(0), None))
    table = {}
    table[tuple(start)] = True

    while not q == []:
        a = q.get()

        for x in adjacent[a.space]:
        b = a.board[:]
        b[a.space] = b[x]
        b[x] = 0
        key = tuple(b)

        if key in table: continue
        c = State(b, x, a)

        if b == GOAL:
            print_answer(c)
            return

        q.put(c)
        table[key] = True


def print_answer(x):
    if x is not None:
        print_answer(x.prev)
        print(x.board)
```

when I run it, it works well without any problem.
such as

```
bf_search([1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8])
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But I have problem if I want to apply it to DFS(Depth first search).

i just change

```
def bf_search(start):
    q = Queue.Queue()
```

to

```
def df_search(start):
    q = Queue.LifoQueue()
```

for change Queue(FIFO) to stack (LIFO).

but it doesn't work well. Even it could find the goal, goal and goal(-1 status) is

```
df_search([1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8])
[3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

in this case (Start point is [1,2,5,3,4,0,6,7,8]), solution(path) of DFS must be same as BFS.

I need help to solve this.